# Title of Neal Asher short story where separatist terrorists are infiltrated by human looking AI, disguised as a fat local farmer?

Tags: story-identification

This is a short story about a Separatist special ops team that has to destroy a communications link of some sort. They have help from local peasant like volunteers. One of these is an AI disguised as an overweight bumbler that mysteriously seems to be losing weight while the Separatists are being gruesomely killed one at a time.

Comment: Are you sure this is Asher? I thought I had all his works but I cannot find a short story matching your description.

Answer (score 2):

Found it. The Rhine's World Incident. It's in The Mammoth Book of S.F. Wars anthology  edited by Ian Watson and Ian Whates (another connection with Ian Watson ). It was first published in an anthology with apparently linited distribution called Subterfuge also edited by Ian Whates. I highly recommend it. I was getting worried that nobody knew about it. But I distinctly remembered it being in Asher's polity universe. I was already searching other space opera universes by British authors like Peter F. Hamilton, Alastair Reynolds etc. Almost started to think I made it up. LOL.

Comment: If you are the poster of the question, you should [merge your accounts](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/help/merging-accounts) so you can accept your answer.  You should also include more details of the story so it's easier for other people searching for the same story to find it.